# How to catch custom events from laravel in vuejs app

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

Making @vue/cli 4.0.5 app with data reading from Laravel 7 Backend REST API I need to 
make some notification from Admin part of the site and all the users who works in 
frontend part the app at this time must to see it.

I suppose that I need in laravel part to send request header( method with custom code
and in frontend part to catch this event in src/App.vue, like :

```
created() {
    let self = this

    Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
        next(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 503) {
                this.$router.push('/MaintenanceMessage')
            }

            if (response.status === MyCustomCode) {
                this.$router.push('/MaintenanceMessage')
            }
            if (response.status == 401 || response.status == 403) {
                // alert( '401 ERROR ::')
```

But I do not know which MyCustomCode can be used here, which are permitted?
If this a valid way ?
Are there some libs/plugins/scripts for this?

```
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.3.0",
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry i couldn't help right now. May I suggest you to use Axios? I don't know if its relevant or not.

Comment: vue-resource or Axios are used when user makes some action : say click on button or move to other  page. That is different : Admin in his area push some event to logged users using the app at this time

Comment: If you have expierence with similar what I need please share it. Hope I clearly explained what I need.